# Export list from SharePoint

Tags: list, export

I want to export a list from SharePoint but when I specify a name for the file, I have an error

> You have to specify a name (in french)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must type a location ( preferably a local location on the server or a shared network location ) and then a filename for your export.

For example: `C:\backups\backupFileName.cmp`

Answer (score 0):

When you export it, you need to provide a path **and** a file name where it will store the exported package. This could be one of the WFE servers or an app server or a network file share.